# Customizing a theorem while taking over the counter from another theorem

Tags: environments, theorems

I defined a theorem within an environment which is numbering like T1.2. for the second theorem in the first section. Now I want to have another theorem which has the same counter as the other theorem but looks like T1.3*.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
\newpage
\section{New section}
}{}

\newtheorem{mytheorem}{}[section]
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{T\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\newtheorem{starredtheorem}[mytheorem]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\begin{mytheorem}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{starredtheorem}
\blindtext
\end{starredtheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I want something like

```
\renewcommand{\thestarredtheorem}{T\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}*}
```

so the numbering in the minimal example should be

```
T1.1. ABC
T1.2*. DEF
T1.3. GHI
```

How can I do this?

Comment: May it happen these environment use the optional argument?

Comment: Yes. In the real document, the environment has an optional parameter which is shown in the header but not the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` command in order to redefine `\themytheorem` in the scope of the `starredtheorem` environment:

```latex
\let\themytheoremNormal=\themytheorem

\AtBeginEnvironment{starredtheorem}{%
  \renewcommand*{\themytheorem}{\themytheoremNormal\relax *}%
}
```

This also works when referencing the theorem, because:

1. The begin code of the `starredtheorem` environment does `\refstepcounter{mytheorem}`, which does a `\protected@edef\@currentlabel{...}` which stores the expansion of `\themytheorem` at that point in macro `\@currentlabel`.
2. `\label{th:starred}` does `\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{th:starred}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}`, which writes a `\newlabel` command to the `.aux` file containing the expansion of `\@currentlabel`, i.e., what `\refstepcounter{mytheorem}` has prepared in step 1 using the special redefinition of `\themytheorem` (the one that appends a star).

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\newpage\section{New section}}
  {}

\newtheorem{mytheorem}{}[section]
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{T\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}
\let\themytheoremNormal=\themytheorem

\newtheorem{starredtheorem}[mytheorem]{}

\AtBeginEnvironment{starredtheorem}{%
  \renewcommand*{\themytheorem}{\themytheoremNormal\relax *}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\begin{mytheorem}\label{th:normal-a}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{starredtheorem}\label{th:starred}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{starredtheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}\label{th:normal-b}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{mytheorem}

References to theorems~\ref{th:normal-a}, \ref{th:starred}
and~\ref{th:normal-b}.

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Discussion of the `\relax`

The `\relax` in the special (“starred”) definition of `\themytheorem` is not really *necessary*, it is just safe practice when using a `*` as text: even if what precedes the star were a command having a starred form, the `\relax` would prevent said command from interpreting our star as meaning “I want the starred form of the command.” In this case, after expansion of `\themytheoremNormal`, what precedes the star would be `\arabic{mytheorem}`, which doesn't behave differently when followed by a star. Thus, the `\relax` isn't necessary, but it doesn't hurt either.

The kind of problem this `\relax` is preventing could occur if, for instance, one were to use (silly-looking example, but it can be tested):

```latex
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{%
  T\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}\protect\\%
}
```

In this case, though, the best practice is to prevent the error *at the call site*. In this example, this is where `\\` is used, since it is the command that will look ahead and behave differently if there is a star coming along. The best fix in this case would be to use:

```latex
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{%
  T\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}\protect\\\relax
}
```

in order to make sure that the starred form of `\\` isn't used. This way, even if someone uses a `*` not preceded by `\relax` afterwards, the call to `\\` will work as a `\\` and not as a `\\*` (which would start a new line, prevent a page break but wouldn't print a star).

Comment: I've added a bit more programming advice regarding the potential problem with the star (which doesn't affect the code in the answer, don't worry: this is only general advice regarding the special status of `*` in LaTeX).